# How to pass the result of a suspending function to a non-suspending function?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-lifecycle, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

Let's say I have the function

```
suspend fun doSomething(): Result {
    val result = doStuff().await() //this is the suspending part
    return result
}
```

I now want to build a generic function which can take functions like the one above as a parameter. Its main goal is to turn the passed result into a livedata object:

```
fun getResultLiveData(resource: Result): LiveData<Result> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(resource)
}
```

However, when I try calling the suspend function to get its result as a parameter, like so:

```
fun someLiveData = getResultLiveData(doSomething())
```

I get an (understandable) precompile exception for the part inside the brackets of `getResultLiveData`:

`Suspend function doSomething() should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function`

This obviously makes sense, but how do i annotate the parameter for my getResultLiveData as the result of a suspending function?

Now, if i were to do something like:

```
fun getResultLiveData(): LiveData<Result> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
    emit(doSomething())
}
```

It would work, because it is being called within the scope of a suspending part of the function (i.e. the `LiveDataScope`). But I just want to go one abstraction step further...

Comment: You are not passing the function as a parameter. You are passing the result of calling the function.

Comment: @CommonsWare I am aware of that, just a small mistake in the post. The title remains and the rest hopefully indicate that I don't want to literally pass the function itself

Comment: Well, actually, that probably *is* the right answer. I didn't feel like trying to hack something together in Android Studio to get the syntax right. But, you need to be calling `doSomething()` *inside* of the `liveData {}` builder. One way to do that is to pass a function type. The syntax should be something like `fun getResultLiveData(thingy: suspend () -> Result)`, though I'm not 100% certain if I have the `suspend` keyword in the right place. Then, `emit(resource)` becomes `emit(thingy())`, calling the function type.

Comment: My train of thought went in that direction as well, however problems start to arise when the suspend function needs parameters itself because you'd have to specify either with vararg or something else. But I'll look into it, maybe I'll come up with a solution. And yeah you have it in the right place, I also read that in another stack overflow reply and tried it for functions with no parameters.

Comment: "however problems start to arise when the suspend function needs parameters itself because you'd have to specify either with vararg or something else" -- use a lambda expression to capture the parameters. So your call would be `getResultLiveData { doSomething(param1, param2) }`.

Comment: Oh wow, that's actually it, thanks a lot!

Comment: If you have stuff working, consider answering your own question, as you have the correct syntax in front of you. Regardless, I'm glad to hear that things are working out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @CommonsWare, the solution is to pass a suspending function itself, and not the result of the function as a parameter. This also works when the suspending function has parameters.

The `getResultLiveData` function should look the following:

```
fun getResultLiveData(resourceFunction: suspend () -> Result): LiveData<Result> = liveData(Dispatchers.IO) {
  emit(resourceFunction())
}
```

And then you could easily call the function within a lambda expression:

```
getResultLiveData{doStuff(param1, param2)}
```

or simply

```
getResultLiveData{doStuff()}
```